# How to customize \name in formal letter MWE is shown below

Tags: formatting, alignment, letters, page

```
\name{FirstName}{LastName}
\address{1 Brookings Dr}{St. Louis, MO 63130}
\phone[mobile]{314-xxx-xxxx}                   
\email{youremail@wustl.edu}             
                   



\begin{document}

% Insert Olin Logo
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{Olin_Logo.jpg}
\end{minipage}


\recipient{Dear Hiring Manager,}{}
\opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
\closing{Sincerely,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
\enclosure[Enclosures]{Résumé, Writing Sample, Transcript}   
\makelettertitle

% body of letter 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

**strong text** I would like to customize \name so that at end of letter after sincerely my name is followed by Ph.D in the same line but in the first line above address it should be only my name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is template you can use.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\name{FirstName}{LastName}
\address{1 Brookings Dr}{St. Louis, MO 63130}
\phone[mobile]{314-xxx-xxxx}                   
\email{youremail@wustl.edu}  

           
%*****************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
    \@closing\\[3em]%
    {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname,~PhD}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
        \\%
        \vfill%
        {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother
%***********************************************


\begin{document}
    % Insert Olin Logo
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth, height=50pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \recipient{Dear Hiring Manager,}{}
    \opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
    \closing{Sincerely,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
    \enclosure[Enclosures]{Résumé, Writing Sample, Transcript}   

    \makelettertitle    
        
    % body of letter 
    
    \kant[1] % some text <<<<<<<<<<
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \makeletterclosing
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I exactly want .